How to set Tanner L-EDIT and convert polygons to boxes
when I use LEDIT v12.x, I can use "Merge" to convert rectangles (polygons) to rectangles (boxes), but in the new version (v16.x) I cannot do this.
I guess I can modify the default parameters through some kind of command (just like the Autocad command), so that the rectangle can be automatically converted to box format when operating commands such as Boolean and merge. But I still can't find the answer. Do anyone know how to set it up? Thanks.
